# Converción_StringHEX_ASCII

Tags: java, ascii

Tengo el Siguiente Código para convertir un valor String HEX a un valor String ASCII, el problema con la función es que para valores que superen los 128 (80 en Hexadecimal) el resultado que muestra no es correcto, alguien podrá decirme cual es el error?
Esta es mi función:

```
public String hexadecimalToASCII(String hexString) throws ParseException {
    String ascii = "";
    hexString = hexString.replace(" ", "");
    for (int i = 0; i < hexString.length(); i += 2) {
       String str = hexString.substring(i, i + 2);
       ascii += (char) Integer.parseInt(str, 16);
    }
    return ascii;
}
```

El valor de prueba es el siguiente "80000000" pero al momento de escribirlo en un archivo se escribe de la siguiente manera "1A000000".

Comment: ¿Lo que esperas es que dado un texto en HEX sea convertido a un texto legible en ASCII?

Comment: SI, ese texto en ASCII lo escribo en un archivo para guardar la información pero al transformar el texto cambia los valores que sobre pasen el valor de 80